# Jquery tooltips for joomla site

Tags: jquery, joomla, tooltip

I want to replace all the java script alert messages and tool tips  with jquery tool-tips in my joomla site.

Comment: In future it's better post such kind of post to your personal blog. Try to come back when you will start implementing your idea to life and will have some problems/errors/question to ask and community would be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a system plugin which onAfterRender():

- searched the output code with regular expressions for javascript alert messages
- injects any jquery includes you need into JDocument
- replaces all of the alerts with your jquery version

HTH, Jochen